# PHP function missing argument error

Tags: php, validation, function

My validate function looks like that

```
function validate($data, $data2 = 0, $type)
{
...
```

Function call example

```
if ($result = validate($lname, 'name') !== true)
        response(0, $result, 'lname');
```

As you see, my validate function has 3 input vars. I'm not using second var - $data2 often, that's why set it to 0 by default. But when I'm calling this function as given example (as far as I know it means $data=$lname, $data2=0, $type='name') getting error message

```
Missing argument 3 ($type) for validate()
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Call like `validate($lname, 0,'name') `

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Missing argument 3 ($type) for validate() <sup>[1]</sup>

*Always* list optional arguments as the last arguments, never before non-optional arguments.

Since PHP doesn't have named parameters<sup>1</sup> nor "overloading ala Java", that's the only way:

```
function validate($data, $type, $data2 = 0) {
}
```

---

- <sup>1</sup> Error with severity `E_WARNING` until PHP 7.0 (including); Uncaught [`ArgumentCountError`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.argumentcounterror.php) starting with PHP 7.1<sup>[rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/too_few_args)</sup> (and starting with PHP 8.0 as well for internal functions<sup>[rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/consistent_type_errors)</sup>).
- <sup>2</sup> before PHP 8.0, see [*Named Arguments*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments)

Answer (score 6):

You should at least  set the $type in this line:

```
function validate($data, $data2 = 0, $type)
```

at `NULL` or `''` as you can see here:

```
function validate($data, $data2 = 0, $type = null)
```

PHP let you to set a value for the parameters, but you can't define a parameter **WITHOUT** a preset value **AFTER** parameter(s) which **HAVE** a preset value. So if you need to always specify the third param, you have to switch the second and the third like this:

```
function validate($data, $type, $data2 = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected

Your should switch the second and third arguments of the function, making the optional argument the last one. So it becomes:

```
function validate($data, $type, $data2 = 0)
{ ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate($data, $data2, $data3, $data4, $data5)
```

im a beginner but i think that you can use a thousand arguments
as long as you call like that

```
if ($result = validate($lname, 'name','','','') !== true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that starting with PHP 7.1 this will throw a PHP Fatal error, not just a warning:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function validate(), 2 passed in /path/to/file.php on line X and exactly 3 expected
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php