# Make it so all variables don't have to be defined when a function is called

Tags: php, function, hosting, warnings

I am using 000webhost and I made a custom PHP function that looks like this:

```
function example($test1, $test2, $test3) {
   echo $test1 . $test2 . $test3;
}
```

Then I do `example('hello');` and it says:

```
PHP Error Message

Warning: Missing argument 2 for example(), called in /home/a8525001/public_html/test.php on line 5 and defined in /home/a8525001/public_html/test.php on line 2

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Warning: Missing argument 3 for example(), called in /home/a8525001/public_html/test.php on line 5 and defined in /home/a8525001/public_html/test.php on line 2

Free Web Hosting
1
```

Is there any way I can stop these warnings without access to the server's php.ini? The same code worked fine on my xampp server...

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: Did you try error_reporting(0) at the top of the file?

Comment: @nevermind I don't think that's the best idea because then I can't see other errors... I found the solution and posted it below. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, and here are a 2 of them:

You could use the following when set to null (having them defined).

```
function example($test = NULL, $test2 = NULL, test3 = NULL) {
    // use variables here but do something like this to check it isn't empty
    if($test !== NULL) {
        echo $test;
    }
    /// etc...and use the rest in whatever you need
}
```

or you could use [**`func_get_args()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), which allows you to go something like this:

```
function example() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $i => $arg) {
        echo "Argument {$i} is: {$arg} <br />";
    }
}
```

Allowing you do something like:

```
example('derp', 'derp1', 'derp2');
```

And the above function would return:

```
Argument 0 is: derp
Argument 1 is: derp1
Argument 2 is: derp2
```

**Optionally**: you could use [**`func_num_args()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) to ensure that there were parameters set in the function.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll do the NULL option. It seems a lot easier. Are there any advantages to the second method over the 1st?

Comment: @Speedysnail6 the second option allows you to use as many arguments as you'd like instead of having to specify each of them like : `example($test, $test2, $test3)`

Comment: @Speedysnail6 does this answer your question?

Comment: yes. I actually found the answer too if you look below but I'll do yours because it's more in depth

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer :D,

To make a variable in a function optional, define it in the code itself such as:

```
function example($test1, $test2 = NULL, $test3 = NULL) {
   echo $test1 . $test2 . $test3;
}
```

Then, the values will already be defined, but when the function is called, if the optional values are defined, it will override the NULL.

Source: [PHP function missing argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065003/php-function-missing-argument-error)