# Missing argument 3 error how can I fix this

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've got

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for wooopenclose::replace_product_link()
>   in
>   /home/content/01/11974901/html/wp-content/plugins/woc-open-close/includes/classes/class-functions.php
>   on line 39

My line 39 look like this:

```
function replace_product_link( $link_html, $product, $args ){
    return $link_html;
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Might be a duplicate: [PHP function missing argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065023/3730754)

Comment: Why you can't initialize the third parameter if you are not sure it will be passed always. The code would be like this:  function replace_product_link( $link_html, $product, $args="" ){

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065003/php-function-missing-argument-error?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function missing argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065003/php-function-missing-argument-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always list optional arguments as the last arguments with default value. Since PHP doesn't have named parameters nor "overloading ala Java" that's the only way:

```
function replace_product_link( $link_html, $product, $args=null ){
    return $link_html;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. It can help future readers as well.

Comment: @ChaowanaPing please upvote/accept the answer so that it would be helpful for others as well. Welcome.